# How to sort numbers in a large text file

Tags: c++, sorting

My task is to sort a large text file (>1GB) where numbers are arranged one per row as in the following example:

```
1906885614
1069046615
1576929003
1690826360
1540261768
786870227
1737467783
295136587
685162468
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    ofstream filtered;
    ofstream filtered1;
    ifstream textfile ("sort_1.txt");
    string text_input;
    map<string, long int> map_data;
    vector<string> sort_vec;
    long int i;

    if (textfile.is_open())
    {
        filtered.open("filtered_list.txt");
        while( ! textfile.eof() )
        {
            getline (textfile, text_input);
            map_data[text_input]++;

            if (map_data[text_input] == 1)
            {
                filtered << text_input << '\n';
            }
        }
        filtered.close();
        textfile.close();
        cout << "Filter Process Complete!" << endl;
        map_data.clear();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to Open file: " << endl;

    ifstream textfile1 ("filtered_list.txt");

    if (textfile1.is_open())
    {
        filtered1.open("Filtered_Sorted.txt");
        while( ! textfile1.eof() )
        {
            getline (textfile1, text_input);
            sort_vec.push_back(text_input);
        }
        sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end());

        for (i = 0; i < sort_vec.size(); i++)
            filtered1 << sort_vec[i] << endl;
        cout << "Sorting Process Complete!" << endl;
        filtered1.close();
        textfile1.close();
        sort_vec.clear();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to Open file: " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the have output seems not to be correct. This is what it looks like:

```
1000107620
1000112250
1000112712
1000113375
1000115080
100011777
```

and something like this:

```
999513319
999515927
999526130
99952947
999531752
999533144
999537
```

It looks like the program ignores the last digits and I don't know why this happening.

Comment: Pease indent the code properly.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited post :)

Comment: it's sorted (in alphanumeric order)

Comment: I really try but I don't understand what is your problem your example of input and output don't make any sense. And your [mcve], doesn't help why do you open 4 files ?

Comment: Try making sort_vec a std::vector<unsigned int> instead.

Comment: You read in the data as character data, and you sorted it as character data.  Nothing is wrong with the output you're showing us, given that fact.  If you want to sort numerically, then you have to sort based on a numeric type (not string).  Also, the problem has nothing to do with large files, even though the title of the thread suggested as such.

Comment: If you can fit the data into memory in a `std::vector`, it's not a "large" file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your input or output. The program is sorting `string` and is not ignoring any char or digits.
**The ordering you obtain is an alphanumeric one**.
Infact executing it on the following input:

```
6
55
444
3333
22222
111111
```

yelds:

```
111111
22222
3333
444
55
6
```

which is clearly ordered alphanumerically.

To fix the problem you can

- make  `vector<std::string> sort_vec`; a `vector<long long> sort_vec`;
  making sure to convert the line you read from the file to a `long long` (or whatever type you like using `std::stoll` function.

Something like the following should work:
`sort_vec.push_back(std::stoll(text_input));`

- Another option is to use a custom comparator. The only change in this case is in the way you call `sort`.

The following alone should do the trick:

```
sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end(),
     [](auto a, auto b){
        return stoll(a)<stoll(b);
});
```

As suggested by  @Toby Speight there is no need to convert the `string`s to numbers (one good reason to do that is that you cannot sort numbers longer that the maximum number of digits of `long long`, because of overflow problems.). One can simply compare the lengths of the stings first and if they're equal then proceed with an alphanumerical compare (taking care of any leading zeros).

```
sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end(),[](auto a, auto b){
    return std::make_tuple(a.length(),a) < std::make_tuple(b.length(),b);
});
```

I have modified your code and the output i obtain is correct:

### input

```
6
55
444
3333
22222
111111
```

#### output

```
6
55
444
3333
22222
111111
```

which is what you want.

Comment: like you advise to use a `long long` you should advise to use `stoll()` and not `stol()`

Comment: Are you sure `sort_vec.push_back(stol(text_input));` ?

Comment: That is a giant typo. I clearly stated in the answer to use `stoll`. Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Even if you're going to use a custom comparator, there's still no need for the costly conversion to integer (and the potential to still be out of range).  You can just `return std::make_tuple(a.length(), a) <  std::make_tuple(b.length(), b);` to sort shorter strings first, assuming the inputs have no leading zeros.  The extension to skip over leading zeros is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Toby that would be definitely a more solid solution. Not sure always much faster. Especially if all numbers have the same length.  I used conversion to `int` to better stress what was the nature of the problem in this specific question.  I will update the answer with your contribution.

Comment: Im very grateful for your answer Davide and @TobySpeight Unfortunately I have some problems with that - one is I have an error: "a doesnt name a type" - before that error I have warning: "auto changes meaning in C++, please remove it". Also in a function sort i have - expected '{' before ';' token - I know it is stupid error, but I trying to solve it and I dont know why it happens - it doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @Adrian - probably you're using an older standard of C++ - you'll want to ensure you're using at least C++11 and preferably C++14 these days.  E.g. `g++ -std=c++14`.  If you don't specify the standards version, many compilers will default to C++03 or worse.

Answer (score 1):

C++ defaults to sorting strings in alphabetical order.  The string `"1000115080"` comes before the string `"100011777"` in alphabetical order because the character `'5'` in the 7th position in the string comes before the character `'7'` alphabetically.  It's the same reason that the word "apple" is sorted before the word "axe", even though "axe" has fewer characters.  To sort these as integers, either convert strings to integers before performing the sort:

```
std::vector<long int> sort_vec;
std::string text_input;

while(!textfile.eof()) {
    long int val;
    textfile >> val;
    // do some error checking here.
    sort_vec.push_back(val);
}

sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end()); // now this is in numerical order
```

or pass a custom comparison function to `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<std::string> sort_vec;
std::string text_input;

bool comp(std::string a, std::string b) {
    if (a.size() < b.size()) { // numbers with fewer digits are smaller
        return true;
    }
    if (a.size() > b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    return a < b;
}

while(!textfile.eof()) {
    std::string val;
    std::getline(textfile, val);
    // do some error checking here.
    sort_vec.push_back(val);
}

sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end(), comp); // now this is in numerical order, but sort_vec still contains strings rather than ints.
```

As mentioned in the comments, you will probably get the wrong answer if you implement option 2 yourself (leading zeros, negative/positive signs, etc.), so better stick with letting the standard library do the conversion to integers for you.

Comment: your second solution will be very slow.

Comment: @Stargateur, it's probably faster than converting to `long`, as `size()` is a constant-time operation, and char-by-char comparison will stop as soon as there's a mismatch.  It is however *wrong* when `b.size() < a.size()` but `b` sorts after `a`.  That's why I recommend `make_tuple` and using its `<` operator (don't worry about the apparent temporary - that soon optimises away).